# Access microphone on internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web, webrtc, html5-audio

i do check the WebRTC for checking the existence of microphone, work form chrome to edge but unfortunately ie doesn't support.
I found some online websites but non on ie do work correctly.
How can i detect if client browser connect with microphone on ie ?

Comment: IE is not in the list of supported browsers for WebRTC.

Comment: that's right, how can i detect if user connect with microphone in ie?

Answer (score 1):

[IE does not support WebRTC](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc) and there's no other method on the browser to get a stream from the microphone.

Though I haven't tested them, there are plugins to add WebRTC functionality to IE, like [Temasys WebRTC plugin](http://confluence.temasys.com.sg/display/TWPP) or [webrtc-everywhere](https://github.com/sarandogou/webrtc-everywhere).